# Do I need to treat the below scenario as critical?

Tags: java, android, aidl, hal, hidl

I have Android java service which will interact with `HAL` service using `HIDL` calls.

I have below scenario, I'm not sure to treat it as critical.

```
+----------+  (AIDL) +--------------+
|App thread|-------->|Java Service  | (HIDL) +-----------+
+----------+         |(SendFunction)|------->|CPP service|  
                     +--------------+        +-----------+
                     ^
+--------------+     |
|AnotherThread |-----|
+--------------+
```

Definition of `SendFunction` is as below.

```
 private void SendFunction(int status, DiagCommandDesc response) {
      try {
          server.executeCommandResponse(status, response);
         if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
              Log.d(TAG, "Response sent to HAL.");
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
             Log.d(TAG, "HAL Server error.");
         }
      }
  }
```

`SendFunction` is being called from two different threads.
Where `server` is an instance to `CPP Server` using `HIDL`.

MY question.

```
      server.executeCommandResponse(status, response);
```

Do I need to treat above `call` as critical and synchronize it? as `server` object will be accessed from two different threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not have to guard the call to `server.executeCommandResponse(status, response)` in your Java service.

The Binder communication is already thread-safe. That concurrent calls to `executeCommandResponse` are safe inside the HAL service has to be ensured by the HAL itself. There is an easy way to make it thread-safe on the HAL side: Using a thread-pool with only a single thread. This will make all other threads wait on the first one to finish, though.

```cpp
int main()
{
    ::android::hardware::configureRpcThreadpool(1, true);
    ::android::sp<MyHal> service = new MyHal;
    if (::android::OK != service->registerAsService())
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    ::android::hardware::joinRpcThreadpool();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can find more information here: https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/threading